# Flask with Summernote And Adding An image - Grabbing The Proper Data?

Tags: html, image, flask, summernote

So im trying to get the information thats being grabbed via summernote textarea. When im not adding an image, everything works perfectly fine and I see the html content from the text editor.
But when I upload a picture, it suddenly gets stuck in a loop??? There more functionality that actually adds the info into the DB, and the image with that ridiculous img src, is saved, but for some reason its iterating the img src over and over? Since then Ive had everything commented out, only to print the textfield content, and for some reason, still get hit with an endless loop the moment I click the submit button? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

flask.py

```
 @app.route("/update", methods=["POST"])
    def update():
    # Grab Text editor content from form:
    contentInfo = request.form["content"]

    print("TEST HERE", contentInfo)
```

html:

```
<form action="/update" method="POST">
 <h1 style="text-align:center">content</h1><textarea name=content id="summernote">{{value}</textarea>
 <input class="input-btn" type="submit" value="Update">
 </form>
```

Script init inline within html:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        height: 300,
        minHeight: null,
        maxHeight: null,
        focus: true,
        onImageUpload: function(files, editor, welEditable) {
            sendFile(files[0],editor,welEditable);
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

So the text editor and everything works perfect, but the moment I add an image and click submit, my terminal gets stuck in an endless loop, literally need to trash the terminal in order to get it to stop before it crashes.
Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Results: Over and Over...

### Well Stack over flow wouldnt let me post an example, but it was just a bunch of what looked like the img src code from summernote over and over

**Update:** - So I changed a few things and at least got it to stop looping. I guess it was never looping what it was doing is literally printing out the content of whats being grabbed and apparently its a bunch of crap. I then instead trying to print it with certain params such as "content["img"] only to find out it was slices, so this is apparently an array: But I throw it into type, and it comes back with a class of "bytes" and a length of 529288.... lol! SO the printing wasnt a loop, it was literally printing the 500k lines of this stupid conversion... (super dumb that summernote compiles their images this way in my opinion) 
Anyways, Wanted to post the current changes, I feel I am starting to get some progress as it is no longer stuck trying to print out 500k lines. Obviously the data thats being grabbed is the overall app converted into byes? becuase I feel the image conversion is around 7k characters, not 500k...

### I feel my issue may be how im trying to grab the data? Since my app is flask and python, it has been a trial an error process trying to get it to work together with the inline javascript. So how my logic works here, is the moment a image is dropped into summernote, it gets thrown into the python logic "updateTest" All im trying to do here, is just grab the image data, so that I can manipulate and do as I wish with the results. How to go about properly grabbing this info? Any advice or insight is appreciated, thanks.

Updated Code:

```
html:
<form action="/updateTest" method="POST">
 <h1 style="text-align:center">content</h1><textarea name=content id="summernote">{{value}</textarea>
 <input class="input-btn" type="submit" value="Update">
```

flask.py:

```
 @app.route("/updateTest", methods=["POST"])
def updateTest():
    content = request.get_data()
    print("test here", type(content))
    print("test here2", len(content))
```

inline javascript within HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote({
            height: 300,
            focus: true,
            callbacks: {
                onImageUpload(files) {
                  sendFile(files[0], data => {
                    let imgNode = document.createElement("img");
                    imgNode.setAttribute('src', data.url)
                    $(this).summernote('insertNode', imgNode);
                  })
                }
              }
            });
        });
 var sendFile = function(file, callback) {
                    var data;
                    data = new FormData();
                    data.append("file", file);
                    return $.ajax({
                      url: "/updateTest",
                      data: data,
                      cache: false,
                      contentType: false,
                      processData: false,
                      type: 'POST',
                      success: function(data) {
                        return callback(data);
                      }
                    });
                  };
```

Any help on how to properly pull this file/image data is really what im looking for right now. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I finally figured it out. Here is the proper code. now I originally wanted this to work with S3 buckets so in the end, going to that route right off the bat, rather than dealing with the crappy conversion summernote tries to do, I recommend everyone else doing the same thing when coming to something like this:

html:

```
<form action="/updateTest" method="POST">
 <h1 style="text-align:center">content</h1><textarea name=content id="summernote">{{value}</textarea>
 <input class="input-btn" type="submit" value="Update">
```

inline javascript within html:

```
<style>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote({
            height: 300,
            focus: true,
            callbacks: {
                onImageUpload(files) {
                  sendFile(files[0], data => {
                    let imgNode = document.createElement("img");
                    imgNode.setAttribute('src', data.url)
                    $(this).summernote('insertNode', imgNode);
                  })
                }
              }
            });
        });
                   var sendFile = function(file, callback) {
                    var data;
                    data = new FormData();
                    data.append("file", file);
                    return $.ajax({
                      url: "/addImgSummer",
                      data: data,
                      cache: false,
                      contentType: false,
                      processData: false,
                      type: 'POST',
                      success: function(data) {
                        return callback(data);
                      }
                    });
                  };
</style>
```

flask.py:

```
@app.route("/addImgSummer", methods=["POST"])
def addImgSummer():
    #Grabbing file:
    img = request.files["file"]    #<------ THIS LINE RIGHT HERE! Is #literally all I needed lol.

    # Below is me replacing the img "src" with my S3 bucket link attached, with the said filename that was added. 
    imgURL = "https://"+ S3_BUCKET_NAME +".s3.amazonaws.com/images/"+ img.filename

    return jsonify(url = imgURL)
```

*NOTE* I have logic elsewhere that adds the data to the S3 bucket, the code above simply renders the result from my bucket. I plan on uploading my code to stack overflow on how to do a full s3 bucket situation with summernote. As this right here was just to finish the conclusion of my initial "Being stuck"

Anyways, hope this helps anyone who gets stuck where I did, as there is literally no proper documentation on how to utilize summernote with flask...(Dont get me wrong theres a lot, but none that work..) And even more so, NONE that utilize a better method than converting your image into a 7k byte character sequence, as I see most people doing... Just saving that horrid crap in their DB... So nothing properly working, at least not that I've found the past 3 days of searching..This right here, is the only working solution Ive come across.

The main confusion lies with mixing the javascript in the front end, and talking with your flask/python backend. Once you now how to grab that data, its smooth sailing.